# how to make elements in a list being displayed repeteviely by multiplying with a given list of strings

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have the following lists:

```py
List_1 = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Pear']
List_2 = [3, 2, 4]
```

I want to create a new list that displays 3x Banana, 2x Apple and 4x Pear.
The list should look like this.

```py
List_3 = ['Banana','Banana','Banana', 'Apple','Apple', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear']
```

Do you have any ideas? how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List_1 = ["Banana", "Apple", "Pear"]
List_2 = [3, 2, 4]

out = [i for i, m in zip(List_1, List_2) for _ in range(m)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['Banana', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to iterate both the lists, and extend an empty list on each iteration, something like this:

```py
result = []

for item, multiplier in zip(List_1,List_2):
    result.extend([item]*multiplier)
    
print(result)

['Banana', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
L1 = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Pear'] 
L2 = [3, 2, 4]

L=[]
for i in range(3):
    L += [L1[i]]*L2[i]

print(L)
# ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear', 'Pear']
```

Answer (score 1):

All methods using zip mentioned here are good enough. This is a method using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) if you want to use:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, List_1, List_2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still new, but thought about this method: Create a dict from your two lists and then use that to generate a new list which meets your needs:

```
List_1 = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Pear']
List_2 = [3, 2, 4]
list_3 = []

InterimDict= dict(zip(List_1, List_2))

for key in InterimDict:
    for value in InterimDict:
        list_3.append(key)
```